# Media player on Linux

Tags: linux, video, ubuntu, media-player, video-player

I'm looking for a media player on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). The important feature to me is continuous playing; so starting from a video, it continuously plays the next video after the previous one is finished (possibly with lowest delay so it will be a smooth watching experience).

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** The number of the files in the directory are not determined in advance, and files are being added to the folder in real-time. The only thing is that they are in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 5):

VLC is the ultimate media player.

- Install the Ubuntu default repository version:

  ```
  sudo apt install vlc
  ```
- Install the latest version (has Blu-ray support):

  ```
  sudo snap install vlc
  ```

How to make a playlist:

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/play-multiple-videos-vlc-49395.html

UPDATE:

Same deal applies

What you can do is run VLC in single instance mode and run this bash command when you have a new file:

`vlc --playlist-enqueue FILENAME`

use `inotifywait` to catch new files

so something like this would work:

Example:

```
inotifywait -m /path -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        vlc --playlist-enqueue $path/$file
    done
```

Credit:
`https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files`

Comment: Why do I need a playlist? The system keeps adding videos to the folder. It is not constant.

Comment: @TinaJ Apologies i did not see the update. I edited my answer.

Comment: Tnx. I will test it. Please make sure the bash script is correct.

Comment: @TinaJ Removed single quotes, This should do it